# Laravel customized session.lifetime at user level

Tags: php, session, laravel-5

I am overwriting `session.timeout` value in one of the middleware (for Laravel web app) but it doesn't seem to be affecting in terms of timing out a session. Though if I debug it shows value I have overwritten.

```
Config::set('session.lifetime', 1440);
```

default value is as following:

```
'lifetime' => 15,
```

Website that I am working on has very short session lifetime for most of the users but for selected users I want to provide extended session lifetime.

Comment: Any solution found?

Comment: I ended up using https://github.com/maxfierke/jquery-sessionTimeout-bootstrap, which is javascript solution which provides auto-logout for users. You can set custom time per user type and have them logout on their respective timeout. Your session.lifetime shall be maximum of any allowed session timeout.

Answer (score 8):

It seems the only way to accomplish a dynamic `lifetime` value, is by setting the value in middleware, before the session gets initiated. Otherwise its too late, as the application SessionHandler will have already been instantiated using the default config value.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

class ExtendSession
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, $next)
    {
        $lifetime = 2;
        config(['session.lifetime' => $lifetime]);
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then in the kernel.php file, add this class prior to `StartSession`.

```
\App\Http\Middleware\ExtendSession::class,
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
```

Comment: Thanks @levi for answer on this old question, I went with something else but haven't tried middleware yet. But seems logical to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

**Here is what worked for me (using Laravel 5.6 or 5.5)** to let a user choose session duration at login time.

Editing the lifetime of the session in Auth controller doesn't work because by then **the session is already started**. You need to add middleware that executes before Laravel runs its own "StartSession" middleware.

One way is to create a cookie to store the user's lifetime length preference and use that value when setting the session expiration on each request.

1. New file:   app/Http/Middleware/SetSessionLength.php

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;

class SetSessionLength {

    const SESSION_LIFETIME_PARAM = 'sessionLifetime';
    const SESSION_LIFETIME_DEFAULT_MINS = 5;

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, $next) {
        $lifetimeMins = Cookie::get(self::SESSION_LIFETIME_PARAM, $request->input(self::SESSION_LIFETIME_PARAM)); //https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Cookie.html#method_get
        if ($lifetimeMins) {
            Cookie::queue(self::SESSION_LIFETIME_PARAM, $lifetimeMins, $lifetimeMins); //https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/requests#cookies
            config(['session.lifetime' => $lifetimeMins]);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

2. Modify Kernel:   app/Http/Kernel.php

Add `\App\Http\Middleware\SetSessionLength::class,` *right before* `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,`.

3. Modify Config:   config/session.php

`'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', \App\Http\Middleware\SetSessionLength::SESSION_LIFETIME_DEFAULT_MINS),`

4. Modify:   resources/views/auth/login.blade.php

To let the user chose their preferred number of minutes, add a dropdown of minutes, such as starting with `<select name="{{\App\Http\Middleware\SetSessionLength::SESSION_LIFETIME_PARAM}}">`. Otherwise, change `SetSessionLength.php` above not to pull from `$request->input` but retrieve from somewhere else, such as a database record for that user.

Comment: Thanks for this, works really well. Works with Laravel 5.5 too.

Comment: It seems not work if session driver is `file`.

In function `createNativeDriver` of core class `Illuminate\Session\SessionManager`, it's sending the configured life time from config as `$lifetime` variable. An important point is manager registrations always run at first moment in process, so overriding config after that does not make sense.


The version I'm using is 6.0.

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs because the session has already started, and after that you are changing session lifetime configuration variable.

The variable needs to be changed for current request, but the user already has a session with lifetime specified.

You have to change your login method. And do following steps:

1. See if user exists in database
2. If yes, and he is user who needs longer session lifetime, run `config(['session.lifetime' => 1440]);`
3. log user in

I recommend using helper to change config on the fly.

```
config(['session.lifetime' => 1440]);
```

Comment: I have tried what you suggested here. I set `config(['session.lifetime' => 1440]);` before calling `Auth::attempt()` still it reflects session time only 5 min for all users.

Comment: Where are you making changes?

Comment: In my controller's login action. Before calling `Auth::attempt` method.

Comment: Laravel version? Code snippet?

Comment: My app is in Laravel 5.2 `if($oUser->user_type == SPECIAL)
                {
                    config(['session.lifetime' => 1440]);
                }

                if (Auth::attempt(['email' => trim($oRequest->email), 'password' => $sPassword]))
                {
                    return redirect('/');
                }`

Comment: In my experience, you need to use a cookie: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59920215/470749