# Laravel session expire time for each session

Tags: php, laravel, session

Can we set expire time for each session in **Laravel**?

If we can how it possible from the controller by each session that we create?
Thanks.

Comment: what you mean by each session you create ??

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can change the session lifetime, application wide by changing the `lifetime` value on `config/session.php`:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => 4320,
'expire_on_close' => false,
```

---

Now, if you want to control the session lifetime per user, you need to set this value before logging in the user.

> 1. Try if user exists in database
> 2. If yes, and he is user who needs longer session lifetime, run `config(['session.lifetime' => $newLifetime]);`
> 3. Log user in
> 4. Enjoy longer session lifetime for current user
>
> — [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45258886/851432)

You have to make the above changes in `LoginController`.

Comment: is that per user? or the whole site?

Comment: @rtfm If we change it in the configuration file, it will be for the whole site. If we change it in `LoginController` as outlined in the above 4 steps, it will be per user.

Answer (score 2):

change the SESSION_LIFETIME= (duration in minutes) @ env