# How to disable "Session Expired in Laravel " in my Login Page?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, authentication, csrf

I wait for 300 seconds in my login page before click the submit button Session expired appear after I click the submit button. but the expected result should be Successfully login.

Do you know how?

Answer (score 5):

There's no "forever" option but you can set it for 20 years or so...

it can be found in

`config/session.php`

just change `'lifetime' => 120,` to `'lifetime' => 20 * (60 * 24 * 365),` **for 20 years**

Answer (score 2):

**You can't `disable` or There's no "`forever`" option but you can set it for 20 years or so**

You can only set it in minutes, but it's just a basic PHP array, if you really wanted to then you could just do the basic math in it if you wanted a longer time.

Like to get an hour, multiply it by 60, to get a day multiply the hours by 24, and to get a year multiply the days by 365.

```
'lifetime' => 1 * (60 * 24 * 365), // 1 year
```

But realistically there's no point and you won't be changing this again so it'd be fine to just put the final result in the config file and leave a comment next to it to note how much the number of minutes equates to.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can make a sessions last forever because they are meant to be expired. If your project requires a longer session lifetime, you can refer to this [StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48859424/laravel-session-expire-time-for-each-session):

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the session lifetime in config\session.php . By default it might be set to 120. Increase it to thousands to prevent session timeout.