# Storing tokens that belong to a model in cache or database in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a web app where a visitor can submit something through an API, and this belongs to a Model, let's say a Post.

Customers that own this Post can set a custom TTL. A visitor can only perform an action once, and therefore we store the tokens. If the token exists, we don't continue. Pretty standard stuff I think.

Tokens are generated with `sha1()` based on the ip and User-Agent.

Currently what I do is 1) check if the token exists in the database: `Token::where('token', $generated_token)->where('post_id', $post->id)->first();`

Then 2) if it doesn't exist, store it:

```
$token = new Token();
$token->post_id = $post->id;
$token->token = $generated_token;
$token->save();
```

Note that the Token model has `timestamps()` so it has a `created_at`.

And lastly, given that customers can set a customer TTL for their Post model, I run a Job every day to check whether tokens need to be deleted based on a comparison of the TTL set and the `created_at` date of the token.

This all works fine, but looking at Laravel's Cache documentation it feels that using Cache this can be simplified. Using the Redis driver, I could add the token if it's not present and then base my logic around that:

```
Cache::add('post:'.$post->id.':token:'.$generated_token, 'value', $ttl);
```

A lot af advantages: less code, no handwritten cleanup logic that can fail, and probably better performance as well.

But I have a few questions here:

1. Give that you retrieve a Cache item by its key, what do I use as it's value? Do I just use something generic like 'visitor-token'? The points below are related to this:
2. Is this really faster vs the DB query? Because the token is tied to a post, the key is quite complex now. is it better like this: `$post->id.$generated_token`? Or do I only use the token as key, the Post ID as value, and then check if we're dealing with the right Post ID in an if statement? Something like:

```
$token = Cache::add('token:'.$generated_token, 'post-id:'.$post->id, $ttl);
    
if(!$token) // token was not added to DB, meaning it already exists
{
   if($token->post-id)
   {

   }
}
```

Couldn't find anything specific to this implementation so hopefully someone has some insights.

Comment: To me this sounds like a scenario for Session. You can also use Session with redis driver and you don't even have to generate tokens. You can just store which posts the visitor has already seen.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a solution based on the Session driver. You don't have to deal with tokens, you don't need a scheduled job to delete old tokens and it's neither more nor less secure than your current solution.

And it consists of just a few lines of code.

Whenever a visitor opens a post I would do this in the Controller roughly:

```
$key = "post_$post->id";

if ($request->session()->has($key)) {
    if(session($key) + $post->ttl > time()) {
        return redirect(route('pleasewait'));
    }
}

session([$key => time()]);
// show user the post
```

Comment: The TTL can be up to 90 days, and if I'm correct a session is removed once someone closes their tab / browser or looses connection (closes their browser) right? If so then sessions would not be the right way to solve this.

Comment: You can actually configure the lifetime of a session, look here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48859424/laravel-session-expire-time-for-each-session 
But in that timeframe the IP of most of the users will likely have changed, too. Normally the ISP will give away new IP addresses every day, I believe. So judging from that standpoint, the Session approach might even be a little bit more reliable.
Otherwise your users have to login, to gain more control over who is who..

Comment: Just as an addendum: I think sessions are mainly stored with cookies and as those are more reliable to identify single users. ISP's will randomly supply IP addresses to their customers and therefore the next day, someone else with the same User Agent might be caught by accident by your token approach..