# Laravel automatically logged out with multiple users?

Tags: laravel, authentication, session, logout

I'm currently developing a website with multiple users.
I tested logging in the other users in incognito and after a few seconds some of them automatically logs out.
When using only 1 user the website doesn't logs out and working fine.
I'm using

I already changed the `SESSION_DRIVER` in to database in the `.env` file but still logging out occurs. Do you know any explanation about this? Thank you.

```
public function grant_auth($name,$section)
    { 
        $data_auth =
        [
            'name' => $name,
        ];

        if(Auth::attempt($data_auth))
        {
            Session::put('section',$section);
            Session::save();
            return Redirect::route('dashboard');
        }
        else
            return Redirect::to('login');
    }
```

Im granting authentication using this code. I didn't use `php artisan make:auth`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48859631/17425602 This answear might do the trick for you

Answer (score 0):

change your config/session.php

```
'lifetime' => 4320,
'expire_on_close' => false,
```

after that clear config cache

```
php artisan config:cache
```

more here: [Laravel session expire time for each session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48859424/laravel-session-expire-time-for-each-session)

Comment: Actually I already did that in the config with the lifetime of 20 years lifetime' => 20 * (60 * 24 * 365) ' unfortunately nothing happens.\

Comment: Maybe you are overriding your 'section' session when you logging in with a different user!