# Laravel memcached - other users are automatically logged out

Tags: php, laravel, memcached

I just changed these two settings in .env file

.env file:

```php
CACHE_DRIVER=memcached
SESSION_DRIVER=memcached
```

After that I cleared config and cache:

```console
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

I have two registered users which are logged in. **User1** logged in non-private, **User2** in private window. When I logged out with **User1**, than **User2** was also logged out automatically.

But if I change the session and cache driver to "file", than it works correctly.

config/session.php

```php
'lifetime' => 120,
'expire_on_close' => false,
'encrypt' => false,
'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
'store' => env('SESSION_STORE', null),
'lottery' => [2, 100],
'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),
'path' => '/',
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', true),
'http_only' => true,
'same_site' => 'none',
```

config/cache.php

```php
'stores' => [
        'file' => [
            'driver' => 'file',
            'path' => storage_path('framework/cache/data'),
        ],

        'memcached' => [
            'driver' => 'memcached',
            'persistent_id' => env('MEMCACHED_PERSISTENT_ID'),
            'sasl' => [
                env('MEMCACHED_USERNAME'),
                env('MEMCACHED_PASSWORD'),
            ],
            'options' => [
                // Memcached::OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT => 2000,
            ],
            'servers' => [
                [
                    'host' => env('MEMCACHED_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                    'port' => env('MEMCACHED_PORT', 11211),
                    'weight' => 100,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
'prefix' => env('CACHE_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_cache'),
```

We tried it on a production server and different devices, same thing happens.

Why does this happen?

Comment: You need to give more informations. You may have a problem in the session handler with memcache

Comment: Can you share the steps you already tried? Like have you cleaned your cache, tried it on different machines etc

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48859631/17425602 This answear might do the trick for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Here is my logout function:

```
/**
 * Logout
 * @return RedirectResponse
 */
public function logout(): RedirectResponse {
   Cache::flush();
   Auth::logout();
   return redirect(self::LOGIN_URL);
}
```

I cleared cache every time when i logged out, so, this was the "bug".