# Laravel Application session timeout from user table

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.6, lifetime

I would like to override Laravel default application session value in `config/session.php` file.

It needs to work for user basics. For example,

> If user Sam set session time out for 10 mins in his user profile preference, the application session only valid 10 mins when his inactive more than 10 mins, then it needs to ask a login again.

In the User table stored the user preferred session time out in one column liked `session_timeout`, so my application only in ideal state which user-preferred session time out only. If there any possibility to override the default session timeout?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change the `lifetime` property (`app/config/session.php`) or better yet change/add the environment variable `SESSION_LIFETIME` to 600 or what you need.

Comment: To set the timeout before the session is started, this works https://stackoverflow.com/a/59920215/42106

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you setup your authentication, the `session.lifetime` isnt actually the duration of the login session. It is the minimum duration of all data you save to the session (using the `session()->put('somekey', 'somedata')` for instance).

So you can still login using the `remember me` option which creates a `remember_web_d01f58ea4edcf9430959ba362b50f014c72a889d` cookie, but before logging in you usually already have a `laravel_session` cookie (or `{APP_NAME}_session`). Discarding the `laravel_session` cookie in this case only resets the session, but you will remain logged in because of the `remember_web_...` cookie.

So with that in mind, you might want to rethink your solution.

If you still want to change the session lifetime, you could try something like this. **Note that I havent tested this and you will likely run into issues**.

This code (without the `$this->app->booted()`) might even need to be moved to a `Middleware` so your `Auth::user()` is sure to have been loaded, and even then I wonder if it will actually cause the session to be expired or extended, because of where this happens in Laravel's lifecycle.

> NOTE the removal of sessions is based on a garbage collection lottery, which basically means that 2 out of 100 requests the sessions will be garbage collected. See the `session.lottery` config. So an expired session might not immediately expire because of this lottery.

```php
// Providers/AppServiceProvider.php
public function boot() {
    $this->app->booted(function() {
        config([
            // Override session lifetime with data from user record.
            'session.lifetime' => Auth::user()->session_lifetime
        ]);
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change laravel env variable on fly

```
$userSessionTimout=$users['session_timeout']; 

config(['session.lifetime' => $userSessionTimout]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work because by then the session is already started. There  is a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59920215/42106